# URL redirects - where and how write it?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have an address in this format subdomain.mysite.com that I would like to redirect to www.myothersite.com I read a lot about it and finally wrote in the .htaccess file of mysite.com the following :

```
redirect 301 http://subdomain.mysite.com/ http://www.myothersite.com/
```

Obvioulsy it doesn't work. Does anyone has a clue for me?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

1) Find out if your website is running on an Apache server. The htaccess file on an Apache web server handles error requests, redirection and other requests.

2) Understand 300 http codes. The code "301" is most commonly used on redirected sites, and means "moved permanently".

3)Type or paste the following code into the text file:

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

“L” indicates that it’s the last instruction and “R” means redirect,   and “301” means a permanent redirect.

4) Learn how to redirect a url with spaces in the name, dynamic pages, sub-domains and other special features by searching online.

5) Change “newdomain.com” to the actual domain name.

6) Click “save.” Change the dropdown list to “all files.” Save the file as .htaccess with no extension.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's exactly what I did in the .htaccess file. But I was talking about two differents sites. A subdomain of mysite called : subdomain.mysite.com should redirect to anothersite.com but it doesn't seem to work even with your syntax.

Answer (score -1):

You can not match against HTTP_HOST in Redirect directive, that is why your code faild.

Try mod_rewrite.

```
 RewriteEngine on


 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

This will redirect

```
sub.domain.com/foo
```

to

```
domain.com/foo.
```